# segmentation fault traversing linkedlist

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have two nodes created in my `main` and i am trying to traverse the list checking for a variable inside each node called a token. I have omitted a bunch of my code that is irrelevant such as

output:

```
   name
    about to enter checknode
    in checknode
    in do loop of check node
    in do loop of check node
    in do loop of check node
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Where are you calling `checkNode()` from?

Comment: Can you try a debug, like `gdb`?

Comment: typedef struct node_ nodeT;

Comment: is that your full `creatNode` function ?

Comment: yes, am i missing something? the actual initialization and linking of the two nodes are in the main.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> I have omitted a bunch of my code that is irrelevant such as the createnode()
> ```

I would say that `createnode()` might be the most relevant here. If you don't initialize your node properly, meaning explicitly set member pointers to NULL, then `next` pointer of such node will have some garbage value. That would explain why you enter the loop for the third time and why it crashes.

edit:

```
typedef struct node_ nodeT;
// ...
nodeT *node=(nodeT*)malloc(sizeof(nodeT*));
return node
```

You want to allocate memory for `nodeT`, so you should pass the size of that type, not the size of the pointer to that type. It should be `sizeof(nodeT)` instead of `sizeof(nodeT*)`. And as I said, members of that struct are not initialized, so `next` will have some garbage value, different than `NULL`, and your checks in loops will fail.

```
headPtr->token=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
headPtr->token="A";
```

This is also wrong. First you allocate some memory and you save pointer to it in `token` and then you save pointer to literal string "A" in `token`. You loose pointer to the memory you allocated, so you have a memory leak. You should use `strcpy()` instead (or `strdup()` and then even `malloc()` won't be needed).

Comment: i added my createnode() and i edited the main to show the malloc(). The malloc and initialization of my variables in the struct for each node are done before any traversing is done.

Answer (score 0):

just by looking at this line `headPtr=createNode();` I can tell that the `createNode()` function is wrong
because you just create a node but don't allocate enought space for it to hold the strings , and thats where the segfault is coming from .and here's  another version of your checking function , yours seem to be a bit messy  :

```
nodeT* checkNode (nodeT* node , char* token)
{
        if(node)
        {
               if(!strcmp(token , node->token))
                {
                       printf("token match\n");
                       return node;
                }
               checkNode(node->next , token);
        }
}
```

**EDIT**
your `creatNode` function is indeed very wrong , and since I'm in a good mood today , here's the corrected version ;) :

```
nodeT* createNode(nodeT* node , char* token , char* fileName , char* instance)
{ 
       if(node)
             node = creatNode(node->next);
       else
       {
             node = malloc(sizeof(nodeT));
             node->token = strdup(token);
             node->fileName = strdup(fileName);
             node->instance = strdup(instance);
             node->next = NULL;
       }
       return node;
}
```

Comment: i just added my createnode() and i added the malloc() in main for 100 bytes for the pointers in my struct as an example and it still doesn't give me any result.

Comment: I added tmpPtr1->next=NULL; in my main and the program worked. Your advice helped but i don't see that much wrong in my code, although you initialized everything in createnode() while i did it in main.

Comment: you should know that "working" doesn't necessarily mean "correct" , something can work even though it's wrong and your code (especially the `createNode` function) is wrong but somehow it's working